# Element UI Datepicker Disabled Date from and Date to

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

```
datePickerOptions: {
    disabledDate (date) {
        return date > new Date()
    }, 
}
```

someone know how to disabled the past date? this code can only disabled the future dates, I want to do is disabled the past and future dates and enable only 3 days.

e.g. Jan 2 is the date today, Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 3 is the enable dates.

[image]

Comment: Please see this code pen https://codesandbox.io/s/ww60k220z8?file=/components/Demo.vue

Comment: @Dineshkarthik thanks for this but I need is both past and future date is disabled and the only enable is the date today

Comment: or only enable is e.g. 24 date today the only enabled is 23,24,25 ? I can't find any solution on this bro @Dineshkarthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Disabling Future date also use `From` in `disabledates`: method

```
<script>
import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker";

export default {
  components: {
    Datepicker
  },

  data() {
    return {
      model: {
        date: ""
      },
      DatePickerFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy",
      disabledDates: {
        from: new Date(Date.now()),
        to: new Date(Date.now()-8640000)
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Image
[image]

you can try with code sandbox which link in mentioned in above comment

Comment: Wow thanks bro! I didn't know there is a from and to